Understanding grpc's async server code flow
I'm failing at understanding the logic of grpc async code flow as explained in this page: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/
It starts with this routine which is called at the initialization of the server service code
void HandleRpcs() {
  // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients.
  new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
  void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
  bool ok;
  while (true) {
    // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
    // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
    // memory address of a CallData instance.
    cq_->Next(&tag, &ok);
    GPR_ASSERT(ok);
    static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
  }
}

Here a CallData object is created on the heap, so its constructor is immediately invoked
class CallData {
public:
  // Take in the "service" instance (in this case representing an asynchronous
  // server) and the completion queue "cq" used for asynchronous communication
  // with the gRPC runtime.
  CallData(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq)
      : service_(service), cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_), status_(CREATE) {
    // Invoke the serving logic right away.
    Proceed();
  }

  void Proceed() {
    if (status_ == CREATE) {
      // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
      // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
      // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
      // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
      // the memory address of this CallData instance.
      service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                this);
      // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
      status_ = PROCESS;
    } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
      // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
      // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
      // part of its FINISH state.
      new CallData(service_, cq_);

      // The actual processing.
      std::string prefix("Hello ");
      reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

      // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
      // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
      // the event.
      responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
      status_ = FINISH;
    } else {
      GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
      // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
      delete this;
    }
  }
}

despite the comments I don't understand why Proceed() is called immediately which means service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_, this); is called immediately (so the request handling code is immediately invoked...?). Plus there's a while(true) loop after the heap object has been created so it goes into the Proceed() twice in rapid succession and the else if (status_ == PROCESS) is immediately invoked..?
I'm not understanding the control flow or the rationale behind this code.

Mostly really good question.  Although I might add a sentence to just make it super clear "I was expecting X but Y happened instead".    If you just say "Why does Y happen?" the answer may be "because they designed it that way".  I think you're just missing one line that explains: when you call Proceed(), what was it that you expected to have happen instead and why?


despite the comments I don't understand why Proceed() is called immediately which means service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_, this); is called immediately (so the request handling code is immediately invoked...?).

RequestSayHello tells grpc to "call us back" when a request comes in. It does not synchronously execute request handling code. The way grpc "calls us back" is by pushing an item in the queue cq_. But that doesn't happen until later, when a request comes in.

Plus there's a while(true) loop after the heap object has been created so it goes into the Proceed() twice in rapid succession and the else if (status_ == PROCESS) is immediately invoked..?

The call to Next is blocking. It will return once there's an entry in the queue (or the queue is being shutdown). Therefore, it isn't called in rapid succession.

I'm not understanding the control flow or the rationale behind this code.

CallData is the state machine of a single incoming request being handled. On construction (CREATE), it tells grpc of its existence. When it shows up on the completion queue, grpc has matched a request to it. Then we call Proceed again (PROCESS) and respond to the request. The response is also asynchronous and identified by the same CallData tag. When the response is complete, we will get another entry in the queue. When we call Proceed then, we will dispose of the CallData.
So... CallData is a simple state machine of a request-response cycle where both the wait-for-request and response are asynchronous.
